# Drupal - blocks don't show after upgrading from 8.5.4 to 8.5.15

Tags: drupal

I am quite the newbie as far as Drupal dev goes. I've been asked to upgrade the core version of an existing website.

I used composer to update the drupal/core package and its dependencies, cleaned the cache, ran the database updates, which went rather smoothly...BUT...

- Some of the blocks are not displayed anymore
- Autocompletion in fields does not work anymore
- My drop-down selects are not displayed (the values they are using are loaded properly)

I have no idea why this happens.

Any hint, anyone?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you see anything in the logs ?

Comment: After searching along the JS line, I noticed that the 8.5.15 version of the core uses a file named jquery-extend-3.4.0.js that clearly triggers that erratic behaviour!